# Question about reflections and eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $R: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ be a linear operator. Then $R$ is a reflection across a plane through $(0,0,0)$ if and only if the following three conditions hold:

- $R$ has a 1-dimensional eigenspace $U$ with eigenvalue $-1$
- $R$ has a 2-dimensional eigenspace $W$ with eigenvalue $1$
- $U \bot W$

Comment: where are you stuck? What is your definition of "reflection"?

Comment: The better question is, "What is your question?" Are you trying to prove this?

Comment: @rschwieb That is my problem. My book doesn't give a definition for reflection. It quickly glosses over it with a definition for orthonormal basis in $\Bbb R^3$ and says that this acts like a reflection. My book is incredibly ambiguous.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Yes. Sorry. I am trying to prove that this is indeed true.

Comment: @Nid Well, it's impossible to get from point $A$ to point $B$ without knowing what point $B$ is.  Sometimes they're defined as orthogonal transformations with determinant $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given no more information, we could postulate that "reflection across a plane (through the origin)" means "vectors normal to the plane have their direction reversed and vectors in the plane are unchanged." Neither one of these conditions can be dropped.

The first half implies that any vector normal to the plane is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$. The second condition implies that any vector in the plane of reflection is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. The fact that the normal is normal to the plane implies the two subspaces are orthogonal.

In the absence of more information about how "reflection across a plane" should be defined differently, this seems like the best approximation. It's just a rephrasing, really.